# Extract object and scalar value via single function

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have to write a query in SQL to extract a JSON path's value. Now the issue is that path's ultimate value can either be a JSON object or scalar value. But in SQL Server, to get the object and scalar value [`JSON_QUERY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [`JSON_VALUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) functions should be used respectively. My issue is that I want to write the same query which returns both types of values. Is there any way in which this can be achieved?

Comment: Sample data, and expected results will help us help you. The fact that you have a column/variable that might contain JSON/might not, however, seems like a design flaw.

Comment: A serialised JSON object is a string (VARCHAR). If you still want both, you could return two columns. Perhaps you could post a sample of what you've tried

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to get the values for a given path `$.foo.bar` like so:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t(
    id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    json VARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO t(json) VALUES
('{ "foo": { "bar": 123 } }'),
('{ "foo": { "bar": "x" } }'),
('{ "foo": { "bar": [1] } }'),
('{ "foo": { "bar": { "baz": 1 } } }');

SELECT *
FROM t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(json, '$.foo')
WHERE [key] = 'bar';
```

The result will contain these important columns:

- `key`: name of the key below `$.foo` which could be used inside WHERE clause
- `value`: the value for the key having datatype = NVARCHAR(MAX)
- `type`: the type of the value having datatype = INT (see documentation)

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0b12dcae2861271a0c5b715c59fc872f)